# wp_head(); crashing apache (xammp)

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

first question here. I'm wondering if you guys can help me.

So I'm trying to pass a static Bootstrap theme website into a dynamic CMS wordpress site. So I coded the site in html/css, showed it to the client and now I'm in the process of turning it into a wordpress theme. Now this isn't my first wordpress site I've made but I do have an issue that has me stumped. I'm trying to link all the stylesheets and scripts through the wp_enqueue function system, and this is what I've come up with so far:

function.php

```
<?php
function wpt_theme_styles() {

  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap' , get_template_directory_uri().'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(),'1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('animate' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/animate.css', array(),'1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('font' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/font.css', array(),'1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('li-scroller' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/li-scroller.css', array(),'1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('slick' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/slick.css', array(),'1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('jquery_fancybox' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('theme' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/theme.css', array(bootstrap),'1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('style' , get_template_directory_uri() . 'style.css' , array(bootstrap),'1.0.0', 'all');

  wp_enqueue_scripts('wow', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/wow.mim/js' , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_scripts('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_scripts('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/slick.min.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery_li_scroller', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery_newsTicker', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.min.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery_fancybox_pack', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_scripts('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/custom.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);


}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", 'wpt_theme_styles');


?>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>8to Mandamiento</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

I've never used this function so it might be very crude or ill constructed, but I've been reading around that echoing in the header the stylesheets is not the correct form of linking it. however when I tried this system all i get is crashes ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gtiz.jpg )

anyone think they can help me put?

Comment: Does it works without adding or executing action for `wpt_theme_styles`?

Comment: @FahadKazmi , it does, but since I'm not executing action it doesn't seem to link the JS/CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer to my own question. Here's what I was looking for.

**To start**, I shouldn't have enqueue styles or scripts directly. Before you enqueue styles or scripts, it's usually a good idea to register the styles/scripts like so:

```
    function octavomandamiento_styles() {
      /* Stylesheets */    
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(''), null, all);
...
... /*Rest of the styles*/
...}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", 'octavomandamiento_styles');
```

for the sake of completeness I'd show a script example too

```
function octavomandamiento_scripts() {
  /* Scripts */

  wp_register_script('wow', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/wow.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('wow',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.mim/js' , array('jquery'), null, true);
...
.../*rest of the function*/
...}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", 'octavomandamiento_scripts');
```

Then the scripts should be loaded properly where you placed the:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
/* and */
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Which should be place in the `header.php` and `footer.php` respectively.

**Secondly** I tried using both enqueues on one single function but this just continued to pop errors on me. I'm sure it is possible to do it all in one but I really can't be f*cked to figure out why it isn't working and honestly it still loads properly.

**Lastly**, theres the fact I had a sintaxis error on my enqueue scripts. you see when you're writing your function and you enqueueing and registering scripts, you're supposed to type:

```
wp_register_script('wow', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/wow.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('wow',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.mim/js' , array('jquery'), null, true);
```

and I had put

```
wp_enqueue_scripts('wow', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/wow.mim/js' , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
```

*Did you catch the error?* it took me a while to figure it out. You have to use the singular **script** when enqueueing and registering but when calling the wp_enqueue action, you have to use the plural **scripts**. It seems very logical in hind sight but oh well. You live and learn.

Hope this post become useful for anyone having this or any other enqueuing issue